# Compare date and pick next value from array in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a json file with a list of holiday info, I would like to compare today's date with the list and display the next upcoming holiday.

How do I do the following?

- Format today's date to compare with holiday json
- Find the next holiday, display it's name and date

**HTML display**

```
<p>Next holiday is {{holiday.name}} on {{holiday.date}}</p>
```

**Holiday Json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Christmas Eve",
    "country": "US",
    "date": "2015-12-24"
  },
  {
    "name": "Christmas",
    "country": "US",
    "date": "2015-12-25"
  },
  {
    "name": "First Day of Kwanzaa",
    "country": "US",
    "date": "2015-12-26"
  },
  {
    "name": "Second Day of Kwanzaa",
    "country": "US",
    "date": "2015-12-27"
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks like you want someone to solve your homework. Please show some effort and learn about arrays and iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other alternative is to use custom directive as below.

```
MyDirectives.directive("drHoliday", function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false, //default
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            items = scope.holidays.filter(function(item) {
                var d1 = new Date();
                var d2 = new Date(item.date);
                return d2 > d1;
            });
            console.dir(items);

            element.html('<p>Next holiday is ' + items[0].name + ' on ' + items[0].date + ' </p>');
        }
    }
});
```

And the markup would be something like below.

```
<div dr-holiday></div>
```

The working fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nju2w59h/).

You can even sort filtered array by date if you are not taking care of same in server side code to make sure that items[0] would be the date you are expecting.

```
items.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function. Call it with your `holidays` array.

```
function getNextHoliday(holidays){

   //Create date with today
   var today = new Date();       

   //Iterate the holiday array in the scope 
   for (idx in holidays) {

      //Create date variable for each holiday
      var holiday = new Date(holidays[idx].date);

      //Compare
      if (holiday > today)
          return holidays[idx].name + " on " + holidays[idx].date;  
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/c6BfQ/277/

I used two filters: one to select dates greater than today's date and another to show only the first such item `<tr ng:repeat="data in data | filter:dateFilter|limitTo:1">`

```js
function dateCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dateFilter = function ($scope) {
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        var today = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
        return (Date.parse($scope.date) > Date.parse(today));
    }

    $scope.data = [{
        "name": "Christmas Eve Last Year",
            "country": "US",
            "date": "2014-12-24"
    }, {
        "name": "Christmas",
            "country": "US",
            "date": "2015-12-25"
    }, {
        "name": "First Day of Kwanzaa",
            "country": "US",
            "date": "2015-12-26"
    }, {
        "name": "Second Day of Kwanzaa",
            "country": "US",
            "date": "2015-12-27"
    }];

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng:app>
<div ng:controller="dateCtrl">What's the next holiday?
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng:repeat="data in data | filter:dateFilter|limitTo:1">
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.country}}</td>
            <td>{{data.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
  </body>
```